no me agrupa los datos de subconsultas por mes - mysql
Tengo 4 tablas donde se relacionan y necesito obtener los siguiente campos: idProceso, Proceso, año, Mes, actividadesAperturadas, actividadesCerradas, actividadesPendientes y totalMatrices.
Esta son las tablas y sus relaciones:

Necesito que me muestre por mes la cantidad de actividades y por proceso. Por ejemplo ejecuto este query y me trae correctamente los datos:
SELECT 
    subconsulta.idProceso,
    subconsulta.Proceso,
    subconsulta.año,
    subconsulta.Mes,
    SUM(subconsulta.actividadesAperturadas) AS actividadesAperturadas
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.id AS idProceso,
        p.nombre AS Proceso,
        YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AS año,
        MONTH(mag.fecha_apertura) AS Mes,
        COUNT(*) AS actividadesAperturadas
    FROM procesos AS p
    INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS mag ON p.id = mag.proceso_id
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT aa.matriz_id, MONTH(aa.fecha_inicio) AS mes
        FROM actividad_acciones AS aa
        INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON aa.matriz_id = ma.id
        WHERE YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ca.matriz_id, MONTH(ca.fecha_inicio) AS mes
        FROM correcion_actividades AS ca
        INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON ca.matriz_id = ma.id
        WHERE YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    ) 
    AS actividades_abiertas ON mag.id = actividades_abiertas.matriz_id AND MONTH(mag.fecha_apertura) = actividades_abiertas.mes
    WHERE YEAR(mag.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    GROUP BY p.id, p.nombre, Mes, mag.fecha_apertura
) AS subconsulta
GROUP BY subconsulta.idProceso, subconsulta.Proceso, subconsulta.año, subconsulta.Mes
ORDER BY subconsulta.Proceso, subconsulta.Mes;

Este es el resultado, enfoquémonos en el proceso de TICS

Yo empecé armando el query de adentro hacia afuera, eso quiere decir por partes, pero cuando hago la unión de las consultas no me esta diferenciando por mes la cantidad de actividades ni de matrices. Este es el query:
SELECT 
    subconsulta.idProceso,
    subconsulta.Proceso,
    subconsulta.año,
    subconsulta.Mes,
    subconsulta.actividadesAperturadas,
    subconsulta.actividadesCerradas,
    subconsulta.actividadesAperturadas - subconsulta.actividadesCerradas AS actividadesPendientes,
    subconsulta.totalMatrices
FROM (
    SELECT 
        p.id AS idProceso,
        p.nombre AS Proceso,
        YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AS año,
        traducir_mes(MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura)) AS Mes,
        IFNULL((
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM (
                SELECT aa.matriz_id
                FROM actividad_acciones AS aa
                INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON aa.matriz_id = ma.id
                WHERE YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(aa.fecha_inicio) = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ca.matriz_id
                FROM correcion_actividades AS ca
                INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON ca.matriz_id = ma.id
                INNER JOIN procesos AS p ON ma.`proceso_id`=p.id
                WHERE YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(ca.fecha_inicio) = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura)
                
            ) AS actividades_abiertas
            INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON actividades_abiertas.matriz_id = ma.id
            WHERE ma.proceso_id = p.id
        ), 0) AS actividadesAperturadas,
        IFNULL((
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM (
                SELECT aa.matriz_id
                FROM actividad_acciones AS aa
                INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON aa.matriz_id = ma.id
                INNER JOIN procesos AS p ON ma.`proceso_id`=p.id
                WHERE aa.cumplimiento = 100 AND YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(aa.fecha_real) = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura)
                UNION ALL
                SELECT ca.matriz_id
                FROM correcion_actividades AS ca
                INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON ca.matriz_id = ma.id
                INNER JOIN procesos AS p ON ma.`proceso_id`=p.id
                WHERE ca.cumplimiento = 100 AND YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(ca.fecha_real_terminacion) = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura)
                
            ) AS actividades_cerradas
            INNER JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON actividades_cerradas.matriz_id = ma.id
            WHERE ma.proceso_id = p.id
        ), 0) AS actividadesCerradas,
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM matriz_de_acciones AS ma
         WHERE ma.proceso_id = p.id
         ) AS totalMatrices
    FROM procesos AS p
    LEFT JOIN matriz_de_acciones AS ma ON p.id = ma.proceso_id
    WHERE YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    GROUP BY p.id, Mes
) AS subconsulta
ORDER BY Proceso, Mes;

Este es el resultado:

Como se puede evidenciar me esta repitiendo la cantidad total del proceso tics (4(mes 8)+4(mes 11)+4(mes 12)) mas no me lo separa por mes como se muestra en el anterior query y lo grave es que los demás campos pasan igual desde el campo actividadesAperturas hacia adelante.

Creo que hace falta explicar, en término de registros, qué consideras una apertura y un cierre de actividad, cómo determinas si una actividad está pendiente y qué es TotalMatrices. Sin esta información, difícilmente alguien puede decir dónde está tu error o cómo construir una consulta que te de lo que buscas.

Estas tratando los registros de actividad_acciones y los de correcion_actividades por igual. Entonces puedes empezar con hacer una unión de las dos tablas.
El próximo paso es agregar los datos. Puedes usar agregación condicional (una condición en la funciona de agregación), para recibir todas las agregaciones deseadas a la vez.
WITH
  dos_tablas_de_actividades AS
  (
    SELECT matriz_id, fecha_inicio, fecha_real, cumplimiento
    FROM actividad_acciones
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT matriz_id, fecha_inicio, fecha_real_terminacion AS fecha_real, cumplimiento
    FROM correcion_actividades
  )
SELECT
  p.id AS proceso_id,
  p.nombre AS proceso,
  YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) AS año,
  MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura) AS mes,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(dtda.fecha_inicio) = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura) THEN 1 END) as abierto,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(dtda.fecha_real)   = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura) AND dtda.cumplimiento = 100 THEN 1 END) as cerrado,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(dtda.fecha_inicio) = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura) THEN 1 END) -
  COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE()) AND MONTH(dtda.fecha_real)   = MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura) AND dtda.cumplimiento = 100 THEN 1 END) as pendiente,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ma.id) AS total_matrices
FROM procesos AS p
LEFT JOIN matriz_de_acciones ma AS ma ON ma.proceso_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN dos_tablas_de_actividades dtda ON dtda.matriz_id = ma.id
GROUP BY p.id, YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura), MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura)
ORDER BY p.id, YEAR(ma.fecha_apertura), MONTH(ma.fecha_apertura);

